# Chrome Extension built on a Mac works fine, does not work when built on Windows or WSL2

Tags: node.js, npm, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Developer A created a Chrome extension in a Mac environment. Built, tested, published and working for all end consumers.

Developer B cloned the repo used to create the extension, built it in a Windows environment and the Chrome extension fails when posting data to an external API. The same is true when building the extension in a WSL2/Ubuntu environment.

**Basic Troubleshooting**

- Verified developers are using identitical npm and node versions
- Verified the zipped extension, built in a Mac environment, works when tested locally in a Windows environment

**Odd Behavior of Extension Built in Windows**

- A popup created by the extension contains an error not present in the 'good' version.

```js
popup.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

And the offending line:

```js
let payload = {}; // Object to hold data payload
```

- Extension retrieves configuration data from a secure external API
- Extension does not post data to a secure external API and does not report any API connectivity errors

Have any of you encountered this? If so, penny for your thoughts.

Update: VSC claimed the file was in UTF8 and, to be thorough, I re-saved the file as straight UTF8. The issue persists. (Thank you for the suggestion, wOxxOm)

Comment: It may be that the script contains UTF8 BOM or another invisible space character. Note that the error may point to an incorrect position in the code, so try verifying it in an IDE or some external tool.

Answer (score 0):

We brought another developer into the mix and found the problem.

Turns out `npm build` isn't sufficient. Our process required `npm run start` in order to create a working deployable extension.

I will expand my answer if I invest the time into determining why this is.

Thanks again.